# Category of partial ordered set

Tags: category-theory

Given a partial ordered set $P$ we can define a category $\cal P$ with $\text{Ob}({\cal{P}})=P$ and for $A,B\in P$ $${\cal P}(A,B)=\begin{cases}\{\cdot\}&\text{if }A\ge B,\\\emptyset&\text{else}.\end{cases}.$$

$\{\cdot\}$ is a single element set.

I don't quite understand this category. Does $\{\cdot\}$ depends on $A,B$? What is the composition map $\{\cdot\}\circ\{\cdot\}$ or $\{\cdot\}\circ\emptyset?$

Thank you!

Comment: You can just understand that there is an "arrow" (which corresponds to $\{\cdot\}$ in your case) from $A$ to $B$ iff $A\le B$. Of course this arrow is uniquely determined by $A,B$, and is a "different" thing if $A,B$ varies. The composition works because $A\le B \le C$ implies $A\le C$ by transitivity, so there is an arrow from $A$ to $C$ which is composition of two arrows from $A\to B$ an $B\to C$. Identity arrow always exist since $A\le A$ for all $A$.

Comment: I suppose $\{\cdot_{A,B}\}$ would be a better notation if that's what's causing you troubles. Then $\{\cdot_{A,B}\}\circ\{\cdot_{B,C}\}=\{\cdot_{A,C}\}$

Comment: What happens if I have $\emptyset$ instead of $\{\cdot_{A,B}\}$ for example?

Comment: If $\{\cdot_{A,B}\}=\emptyset$ then what we have is $B\le C$ and that $A$ is not contained in $B$. Now $A$ could contain $C$ or is contained in $C$ or none of these could happen. We don't have any information. But axioms for Category does not account anything for composition of an arrow and empty set. It only says that when $A\to B\to C$ then there must be an arrow $A\to C$ given by $(A\to B) \circ (B\to C)$. So your question is irrelevant here

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: While this is probably not very accessible at the beginning, I prefer to think of this situation as a category "enriched" in **2** (or, equivalently, as a [(0,1)-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%280%2C1%29-category)).  This makes Hom just a reflexive and transitive relation on objects. **2** itself can be viewed as a [(-1)-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28-1%29-category).  The point is posets are a kind of decategorification of categories which makes them more significant and more interesting than they might at first seem. Decategorifying things is often illuminating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each pair of objects A and B, the hom-set ${\cal{P}}(A,B)$ has exactly one arrow if $A\geq B$ and no arrow otherwise.  This is by definition.  If $A\geq B$ and $B\geq C$ then by transitivity $A\geq C$ so ${\cal{P}}(A,C)$ has an arrow.  The composite of the arrow in ${\cal{P}}(A,B)$ and the arrow in ${\cal{P}}(B,C)$ must necessarily be the arrow in ${\cal{P}}(A,C)$. Associativity and the existence of an arrow in ${\cal{P}}(A,A)$ for every object $A$ is then easy to check. You may have been confused by the fact that your source used the same symbol for every arrow. It would be clearer to call the arrow in ${\cal{P}}(A,B)$ something like "$AgB$".